# Questions about English Literature

Tags: discussion, support, on-topic-off-topic, appropriate-questions

Questions Requesting Explanation

When we fail to find a satisfying or sophisticated answer on the Internet or in our books, can an explanation of poems or dialogs or certain Shakespearean lines be asked here?

Comment: I think this answer by Andrew Leach pretty much nails the difference between literary criticism and about language : http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/5261/44619

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over [eighty questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shakespeare?sort=votes&pageSize=50) have been asked about Shakespeare, and some specifically asked about pronunciation, or the meaning of lines in his plays.

1. [Pronunciation of 'host' in Shakespeare's time](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72937/pronunciation-of-host-in-shakespeares-time)
2. [Thank thou or Thank thee](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/284434/thank-thou-or-thank-thee)
3. [Searching for a literary term for “if this, then I’m a this” statements](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/86749/searching-for-a-literary-term-for-if-this-then-i-m-a-this-statements)
4. [Shakespeare's Scansion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/283375/shakespeares-scansion)
5. [Is "worser" correct grammatically?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/203865/is-worser-correct-grammatically)
6. [What does Macbeth mean when he says his heart is "seated"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/300305/what-does-macbeth-mean-when-he-says-his-heart-is-seated)
7. [The meaning of "yet" in "Ere yet the salt of most unrighteous tears had left the flushing in her galled eyes"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202901/the-meaning-of-yet-in-ere-yet-the-salt-of-most-unrighteous-tears-had-left-the)
8. [Why does Hamlet not say, "ere he rots?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/163132/why-does-hamlet-not-say-ere-he-rots)
9. [What did Shakespeare mean by "gild refined gold"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/267244/what-did-shakespeare-mean-by-gild-refined-gold) (although this question has been closed)
10. [What does this mean: To be thus is nothing; But to be safely thus](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32874/what-does-this-mean-to-be-thus-is-nothing-but-to-be-safely-thus)

So... let's say users *can* ask about specific lines from Shakespeare's works as long as they explain what they do not understand, and show they have done some research. It's an act of courtesy towards EL&U users as it will save them time looking up the same references, and it has the added benefit of making the question more interesting. A note of warning; it is ***not*** enough to say:

> I Googled the quotation, but I didn't get the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 7):

We don't do interpretations of writing on this site, but you can ask in our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage). You may find some people who are interested in talking over author intent and artistic meaning.

Comment: No one replies there

Comment: @Abcd What Kit said was you _may_ find some people interested there, which implies that you may also find that the ones there at the time you ask are _not_ interested. So It's not guaranteed.

Comment: @Abcd Also, *demands* (as opposed to *requests*) for answers are unlikely to be favourably considered.